# Is there a way to limit the area which can be dragged?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpe9yLv7/1), I have a box which I can drag throughout the body. However, is it possible to only be allowed to drag it when the user selects the purple part with an id of head?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#box" ).draggable({containment: "#container"});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use handle

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  handle: "#head"
});
```